# What is the correct way to instantiate a client-side (Typescript) AWS Rekognition client?

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-sdk

I have a front-end app built with Next/React.
I'm attempting to create an image moderation feature using AWS Rekognition via the v3 Javascript AWS SDK.

I have an AWS Cognito Identity Pool configured which hooks into a User Pool.
The interface using Rekognition becomes available once the user has signed in.

I've checked the v3 documentation, but see [conflicting](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v3/developer-guide/getting-started-browser.html) [code examples](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v3/developer-guide/loading-browser-credentials-cognito.html) for how to instantiate client credentials using `fromCognitoIdentityPool()`, both of which give me typing errors.

The following code is giving me a type error for the `client` when passed to `fromCognitoIdentityPool()`:

```
import {
  RekognitionClient,
  DetectModerationLabelsCommand,
} from '@aws-sdk/client-rekognition';
import { fromCognitoIdentityPool } from '@aws-sdk/credential-providers';
import { CognitoIdentityClient } from '@aws-sdk/client-cognito-identity';

const AWS_REGION = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_AWS_REGION;
const AWS_IDENTITY_POOL_ID = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_COGNITO_IDENTITY_POOL_ID;

const moderateImage = async (imagePath: string) => {
  const client = new RekognitionClient({
    region: AWS_REGION,
    credentials: fromCognitoIdentityPool({
      identityPoolId: AWS_IDENTITY_POOL_ID!,
      client: new CognitoIdentityClient({ region: AWS_REGION }),
    }),
  });

  const base64Image = imagePath.split(';base64,').pop();
  const imageBuffer = Buffer.from(base64Image as string, 'base64');
  const params = {
    Image: {
      Bytes: imageBuffer,
    },
    MinConfidence: 70,
  };

  const command = new DetectModerationLabelsCommand(params);
  const response = await client.send(command);

  return response;
};

export default moderateImage;
```

With the error:

```
Argument of type '{ identityPoolId: string; client: CognitoIdentityClient; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'FromCognitoIdentityPoolParameters'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'client' does not exist in type 'FromCognitoIdentityPoolParameters'.ts(2345)
Argument of type '{ identityPoolId: string; client: CognitoIdentityClient; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'FromCognitoIdentityPoolParameters'.
```

What's the correct way to instantiate the Rekognition client?

Comment: check your link to the DEV Guide. Its not resolving

Comment: Can you provide the complete code so I can see your imports?

Comment: It would also be helpful if you could provide the precise error you're seeing.

Comment: @Corey - Thanks for taking a look. I've added the full code and the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try getting `fromCognitoIdentityPool` from `@aws-sdk/credential-providers` instead of `@aws-sdk/credential-provider-cognito-identity`. The latter is not recommended.

I can't find that recommendation in the new docs, but it's in the old ones. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/modules/_aws_sdk_credential_provider_cognito_identity.html

Here's the docs on the `credential-providers` version. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/Package/-aws-sdk-credential-providers/Variable/fromCognitoIdentityPool/

You can omit the `client` parameter altogether if you have your credentials configured locally. But, if not, the `credential-provider` version only takes a `clientConfig`.

```
import { fromCognitoIdentityPool } from "@aws-sdk/credential-providers";
import { RekognitionClient } from "@aws-sdk/client-rekognition";

const rekClient = new RekognitionClient({
  region: "us-east-1",
  credentials: fromCognitoIdentityPool({
    identityPoolId: "redacted",
    clientConfig: { region: "us-east-1" },
  }),
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this - upvoted. I've changed from the deprecated package to the one you've suggested - there's still an error on the same `client` option, but the error has changed. I've updated the code and error in my original post.

Comment: I notice that the same example code on the NPM page for that package uses `clientConfig` rather than `client`... Could that be related? https://www.npmjs.com/package/@aws-sdk/credential-providers

Comment: Although that gives me a different error...

Comment: Updated my answer with something else to try.

Comment: I'd tried removing the `client` altogether - I get a "Region is missing" error, even though I'm passing a `region` option to `RekognitionClient` itself :-\

Comment: And if I try just using `clientConfig: { region: AWS_REGION },`, I get a `NotAuthorizedException: Unauthenticated access is not supported for this identity pool.`

Comment: @RichardHorrocks The NotAuthorizedException is a step forward! It sounds like you haven't set up guest access in your identity pool. You can do that on the 'User access' tab in the console.

Comment: Ah.. okay, this is maybe where I've gotten things wrong :-) I don't want to allow guest access. What I want to allow users to sign in using Cognito (which works), and then allow members of the User Pool to be able to call the Rekognition API. When I instantiated the Identity Pool I added the User Pool under Authenticated Access... Is that how it should work?

Comment: You've got the right idea! Checkout the "logins" property here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v3/developer-guide/loading-browser-credentials-cognito.html
That said, we've digressed a bit, and if you're satisfied with the answer to your original question please consider accepting it.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time on this @Corey :-) I'll take a look at the logins flow. Thanks!